# Fan running almost constantly

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

Quite recently, my late 2012 Mac Mini went from being virtually silent, to having the fan on quite hard nearly all the time, regardless what I'm doing. If I use some 3D rendering or similar then it understandably gets flat out, but if I am doing nothing at all the fan is still a constant whir. I am not using different applications to the past... basically browser and Parallels, but in my Parallels session all I run is RDP.

[image]

Chrome and related processes seem very high CPU% but I don't know if that's normal.

I'm slightly worried my CPU being flat-out risks damage and also that electrical use is high. What can I do to identify and address this issue?

[image]

Comment: When was the last time it was stripped & cleaned?

Comment: Also, what happens after a fresh reboot? In the screenshot your CPU usage is high. (After reboot and without Chrome running. That gets hijacked via rogue plugins a lot.) Other browsers with the same high demands on the pages you visit?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that, for some reason, your system isn’t able to properly cool itself. I recommend trying to reapply thermal paste or bringing your Mac to an Apple Store so they can do it for you.